# How difficult it is to redirect broken links based on keyword matching?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, blogger

I currently host a blog on blogger under my own domain. The problem with blogger is that one cannot change the URLs. Page URLs contain "/p/", blog post URLs contain date (which don't even have to correspond to the actual publication date). If at some point I were to move to a self hosted solution and change the URL structure to something more user friendly, how would I redirect the broken links to new URLs, based on extracting the keywords from the old link? Does ASP.NET MVC offer an easy way to implement that?

I ask because I would like to stay with blogger for a little more, but wouldn't like to pay the price in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Check out IIS Url Rewrite: http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite